# onBindViewHolder doesn't change visibility of ImageView

Tags: java, android-recyclerview

What I'm trying to do is to enable drag and drop on a recyclerview when the user enter in action mode.
Edit: I heavily refactored my code, however the problem persist. Whenever the list of the adapter is modified, onBindViewHolder doesn't set the imageview as visible. Here is the updated code:

```
public abstract class DragAndDropListAdapter<T extends Identifiable, VH extends DragAndDropViewHolder>
        extends ListAdapter<T, VH> implements ItemTouchHelperListener {

    private final ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper;
    private boolean dragEnabled;

    public DragAndDropListAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super(new DiffUtilCallback<>());
        DragAndDropCallback callback = new DragAndDropCallback(this);
        itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VH holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(dragEnabled, itemTouchHelper);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return getCurrentList().get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public void swapCards(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>(getCurrentList());
        Collections.swap(list, fromPosition, toPosition);
        submitList(list);
    }

    public void setDragEnabled(boolean dragEnabled) {
        this.dragEnabled = dragEnabled;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, getItemCount());
    }

}
```

```
abstract class DragAndDropViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    final ImageView handle;
    private ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper;

    public DragAndDropViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        handle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_drag_handle);
        handle.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                view.performClick();
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    itemTouchHelper.startDrag(DragAndDropViewHolder.this);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void bind(boolean dragEnabled, ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper) {
        handle.setVisibility(dragEnabled ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        this.itemTouchHelper = itemTouchHelper;
    }

}
```